# Differece between [viewController.view removeFromSuperView]; and [viewController removeFromParentViewController];?

Tags: ios, xcode, view, uiview

What's the difference between

```
[viewController.view removeFromSuperView];
```

and

```
[viewController removeFromParentViewController]; ?
```

I just want to remove a subview from UIScrollView, of course the code should be like this `[viewController.view removeFromSuperView];`

but when I try `[viewController removeFromParentViewController];` it seems functional as well. weird!

Comment: They do different things on objects of different classes... I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but use the first to remove a view from it's super view and the latter to remove a viewController from it's parent in the controller hierarchy - it's two completely different things.

Comment: Well as you see in the first one you are dealing with a `UIView` but in second one with a `UIViewController` !